# R: default palette used for pie charts

Tags: r, r-base-graphics

I would like to add a legend to a pie chart in `R`
The default color palette is fine for me, but how can I use it in the legend (to match the colors of the plot)?

```
pie(table(iris$Species))
legend('right',c('A','B','C'), fill = colors(3))
```

(I know that I could create a vector of colors to use in the chart in the legend in advance like in `my_colors <- colors(3)`, but this would then not be the default colors.
The official documentation only says that the `pie()` function uses *"pastel"* colors if the `col` argument is omitted, but doesn't specify the exact values.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the body of the `pie` function, you will see that the colors are hard-coded into it in the following lines:

```r
   if (is.null(col)) 
        col <- if (is.null(density)) 
            c("white", "lightblue", "mistyrose", 
                "lightcyan", "lavender", "cornsilk")
        else par("fg")
```

So, you can use the same colors yourself in the call to `legend`

```r
pie(table(iris$Species))
legend('right', c('A','B','C'), fill =  c("white", "lightblue", "mistyrose"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that solves my problem. I should have looked at the code. I didn't expect the colors to be hard-coded.